# How to use multiple images in a single job of gitlab pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I have been trying to use multiple images in a gitlab template

Use Case:

As soon as the image is build using the kaniko image, I need to scan the image using orca-cli for vulnerabilities. I don't want to create a separate template or stage.
Just want to integrate orca-cli image scan after the image is pushed to registry.

Whenever I have tried it with services, it throws error as orca-cli not found or. orca not found when used as alias.

Below is the code content

container-build-template.yml

```
.container-build-template:
  stage: build

  # We need to pre-create the ECR repository but we can't add the aws cli tool into the kaniko image
  # nor can we add kaniko into the aws image so we just do this to create the repository if needed
    services:
     - name: public.ecr.aws/aws-cli/aws-cli
       entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
       command: ["aws --region us-coast11 ecr create-repository --repository-name ${CONTAINER_NAME,,}"]
     - name: ghcr.io/orcasecurity/orca-cli:latest
       alias: orca # <---- This also doesn't work
  

  variables:
    CONTAINER_NAME: $CI_PROJECT_NAME
    CONTAINER_TAG: $BUILD_VERSION    
    CONTAINER_BUILD_CONTEXT: .  
    ECR_REGISTRY: "abc.docker.ecr.us-coast-11.amazonaws.com"
    DOCKERFILE: Dockerfile
    KANIKO_EXTRA_ARGS: ""
    PROJECT_KEY: "test"

  secrets:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: some_key1
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: some_key2
    ORCA_SCAN_API_TOKEN: some_key3
      

  image:
    name: docker-public.us.test.com/vi-kaniko

  script:
    - CONTAINER_NAME=$(echo $CONTAINER_NAME | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]") # force container_name to be lower case
    - CONTAINER_TAG=${CONTAINER_TAG:-${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}}
    # Some code to create & push image to ecr
    - /kaniko/executor --context "${CONTAINER_BUILD_CONTEXT}"
                       --registry-mirror dockerhub.us.test.com
                       --dockerfile "${DOCKERFILE}"
                       --destination "${ECR_REGISTRY}/${CONTAINER_NAME}:${CONTAINER_TAG}"
    - echo "Processing Image Scan via Orca Cli"
    - echo $CONTAINER_NAME
    - echo $CONTAINER_TAG

    # tried with apk, apt, apt-get, yum, df - None of them worked 
    - apt update
    - apt install -y curl
    - curl -sfL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/orcasecurity/orca-cli/main/install.sh' | sudo bash -s -- -b /usr/local/bin
    - orca-cli image scan docker-public.us.test.com/${CONTAINER_NAME}:${CONTAINER_TAG} --project-key ${PROJECT_KEY} --api-token ${ORCA_SCAN_API_TOKEN} --disable-secret --exit-code 0
```

Comment: If the image `ghcr.io/orcasecurity/orca-cli:latest` just provides the CLI binary, I don't think you needs this defined in `services:` --  you just need to install the CLI as part of your job (or use an `image:` for your job that already has both kaniko and orca-cli installed). Can you share any [error] or problem output you have in your job log when run as-written?